# OBIEE ADF integation

Tags: oracle-adf, obiee

My requirement is show dashboard on my adf screen based on user role .
For this I created three dashboards

Dashboard1- assigned to role1
Dashboard2- assigned to role2
Dashboard3- assigned to role3 .

I created a adf page which contains the three Obiee dashboards( using )

Now whenever a user with roles(role1 and role2) logs into my adf application ,he should be shown only Dashboard1 and Dashboard2.
I achieved this by setting permission to dashboard in obiee, but the problem is that " Access denied for Dashboard3" message is shown for the Dashboard3 .

How can i overcome it or is there any way where i can render only those dashboards which are assigned to the logged in user.
Is there any API exposed by obiee which gives me the dashboard assigned to a particular user.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rendered attribute in the dashboard and fill it with the following expression 
**#{securityContext.userInRole['role1']}** which will only get displayed when the user has role1

You need to have ADF Security enabled... If you didn't enable it, you can learn how from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/b31974/adding_security.htm)